# Is a python ".exe" file same as a python ".py" file?

Tags: python, file, path, exe, cx-freeze

I created a ".exe" file from my python file using cx_freezer :

```
# setup.py file
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name="3BV",
    version="1.0",
    description="Create tailored boxes for books.",
    executables=[Executable("C:\Desktop\Boardode\main.py", base="Win32GUI", targetName="3BV.exe")])
```

I need to use 2 txt files that need to be in the exe directory :

```
exe_path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
square       = str(exe_path)+r"\single_box.dxf"
bs           = str(exe_path)+r"\Big_Square.dxf"
```

When I use my main.py to create what I need, it works perfectly, but when I use my ".exe" file, it does nothing, and I can't figure out why.

I repeat, I just turned my ".py" file in a ".exe" file, and added 2 txt file in the exe directory.

Answer (score 1):

They are far different from each other. The `.py` file is your python's source file where your main python code resides. When you have to ship your product, you create an executable (`.exe` file) of it. Because the executable runs on any system whether it's python installed on it or not. On the other hand, the `.py` file need a compiler to compile it & convert to machine code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I knew that, By saying if they were different I meant is the code changes while being converted, of course not but we never know. My problem is that with exe file that I've just converted, the program doesn't work like the initial file

Comment: Yes it changes. In a typical `.exe` file headers are added acc. to the platform & the CPU. Also the exe is made compatible as per the language.

Comment: so how can know what change during the conversion ? and how can I fix it ?

Comment: I don't have any errors, here's is the thing : when I launch my .py file, I need to enter 2 paths, one being the "dimension file" and the other one being the "result directory". After entering the 2 paths, I get a bunch of new files in the result directory. BUT, when I convert this SAME .py file to an exe, and repeat the process, 0 new files are created.

Comment: It might be some other problem